# Recursive mixin in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, recursion, mixins

I want to create a recursive mixin in Dart. Here is what I've tried:

```dart
mixin A<T extends Object> on Object {
  List<Object?> get list;
  List<Object?> get _list => [if (super is A) ...super._list, ...list];
}
```

But this code gives me an info lint that tells me `super` is always `A`, but also `._list` is not defined in `super`.

If I try and fix the second lint by doing this:

```dart
List<Object?> get _props => [if (super is A) ...(super as A)._props, ...props];
```

It gives me a new lint saying that `super as A` is an unnecessary cast.

What I want to achieve here, is a `Mixin` that when added to a base class, the `_list` will have the same contents as the `list`. But when I have an extended class from the base one, if I override the `list`, this class `_list` will have the base class `list` added to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot treat `super` as an object of its own in Dart, so what you are attempting is not possible, as you cannot ensure that there exists a `super._list` property. That is what `on` is normally for, but you cannot have a mixin depend on itself.

Some alternative ways to do this would be:

- Make an abstract class that declares the `_list` property, and have classes that mix-in this mixin extend it
- Make including `super`'s items the responsibility of the subclass, indicating this with [`package:meta`'s `@mustCallSuper` annotation](https://pub.dev/documentation/meta/latest/meta/mustCallSuper-constant.html)

  <sub>This is a common pattern for this type of additive usecase - Flutter widgets, for example, make heavy use of it.</sub>